# Cannot get devise_invitable to assign a role when inviting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am using devise and devise_invitable in my application.  When I send an invite to a user, I also want to assign a role to them.  I added a role_id to my users table via a migration, and created a Role model that contains the allowed roles.  Using some advice found in the documentation for devise and devise_invitable, I added some code to my Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :role_id
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) << :role_id
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :role_id
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :role_id
  end
end
```

In the view, I have this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(User.new, url: user_invitation_path,
                              html: { class: 'form-inline' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email, placeholder: 'Email', label: false %>
  <%= f.collection_select :role_id, Role.all, :id, :name, {} %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Invite User', class: 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Everytime I a create a new user by entering the address and selecting a role, the role_id is still nil (it doesn't get set).

If I add some logging to the beginning and end of configure_permitted_parameters, nothing is failing inside that method.  Right after it finishes though, I see this in my server output: Unpermitted parameter: role_id.

What am I missing!?

Comment: This is using Rails 4, devise 3.4.1, and devise_invitable 1.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `:role_id` parameter to the invite action:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:invite) << :role_id
```

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#strong-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and solved like this:

If you want to set role as sent by your form in view then you are just required to add this to you `invitations_controller.rb`

```
private
  def invite_resource
      resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter) do |invitable|
      invitable.update!(role: invite_params[:role]) #setting role
    end
  end
  def invite_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email,:invitation_token, :role) #overriding params
  end
```